# Matlab Compiler and Startup script

Tags: matlab, matlab-deployment, matlab-compiler

So I'm trying to use the Matlab Compiler in order to build a standalone application which to run on a separate machine using MCR. The actual application follows this [guide](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/examples/benchmarking-a-b-on-the-gpu.html) to benchmark GPU. When I open matlab following [this](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2010/11/18/deploying-standalone-applications/) I make the following command:

```
mcc -mv -o gpuTest mainBench.m benchFcn.m executeBenchmarks.m getData.m paralleldemo_gpu_backslash.m timeSolve.m waitForCpu.m waitForGpu.m
```

The output is:

```
Compiler version: 5.1 (R2014a)
Dependency analysis by REQUIREMENTS.
Parsing file "/media/hdd/work/matlab/gpuBench/mainBench.m"
    (Referenced from: "Compiler Command Line").
Parsing file "/media/hdd/work/matlab/gpuBench/benchFcn.m"
    (Referenced from: "Compiler Command Line").
Parsing file "/media/hdd/work/matlab/gpuBench/executeBenchmarks.m"
    (Referenced from: "Compiler Command Line").
Parsing file "/media/hdd/work/matlab/gpuBench/getData.m"
    (Referenced from: "Compiler Command Line").
Parsing file "/media/hdd/work/matlab/gpuBench/paralleldemo_gpu_backslash.m"
    (Referenced from: "Compiler Command Line").
Parsing file "/media/hdd/work/matlab/gpuBench/timeSolve.m"
    (Referenced from: "Compiler Command Line").
Parsing file "/media/hdd/work/matlab/gpuBench/waitForCpu.m"
    (Referenced from: "Compiler Command Line").
Parsing file "/media/hdd/work/matlab/gpuBench/waitForGpu.m"
    (Referenced from: "Compiler Command Line").
Parsing file "/opt/MATLAB/R2014a/toolbox/compiler/deploy/deployprint.m"
    (Referenced from: "Compiler Command Line").
Parsing file "/opt/MATLAB/R2014a/toolbox/compiler/deploy/printdlg.m"
    (Referenced from: "Compiler Command Line").
```

Than on the other machine, given that the environmental variables are set I just execute the command

```
./gpuTest
```

The resulting error is:

```
Cannot CD to /media/hdd/work/matlab (Name is nonexistent or not a directory).    
Error in startup (line 1)
```

Problem is there is no "startup" script from the one that should have been compiled. However I do have a "startup.m" script which in my startup folder which in fact exactly executes "cd /media/hdd/work/matlab" and some other stuff.

I have 2 questions:

1. Why the heck is it compiling also my startup script at all?
2. How can I fix this to just execute the main script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer both your questions:

1. It's compiling your `startup.m` script so that it can ensure that your main script runs exactly the same as it would in your regular MATLAB session. You'll find that it also includes a bunch of other stuff as well that's needed, such as your preferences folder, which is again needed to ensure that it runs the same as it does in a regular MATLAB session.
2. @matlabgui has already provided a similar answer, which is to apply `isdeployed` within your startup script to block out anything that you don't want to run in the deployed version. Personally, I usually put the following at the top of my startup script, to just block everything.

`startup.m`

```
if isdeployed
    return
end
```

Answer (score 0):

change your startup script to have:

```
if ~isdeployed
   cd /media/hdd/work/matlab
end
```

Why - I dont really know - I guess its so you could initiaise some stuff but its not a "feature" that I have ever utilized....